# Server side script not working after form validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

hy!
I have a signup form. I want to submit form using ajax after complete validation.I used jquery plugin for validation. But as soon as, i simply click on any field, the ajax request automatically sent to server and return a response before hitting submit button.
Also, I am getting the "missing value" message.
I do not know, where is the mistake.
Help me !

Validation.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#signup_form').formValidation({

        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {

            }
        })
        .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
                $('#signup_form').data('formValidation').resetForm();

        });
});
```

form_signup.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#signup_form').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
 $(function(){
        $("#signup_form").click(function(event){
            //event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                    url:'form_process.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(result){
                       alert(result);

                    }

            });
        });
    });
    });
```

form_process.php

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
require_once './functions/functions.php';

if(isset($_POST['FirstName']))
{
     echo $firstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
   }
else{ echo ("missing value!");}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your were calling ajax on form click inside form submit ?? , you need to call it on form submit instead !

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#signup_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                url:'form_process.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: $('#signup_form').serialize(),
                success:function(result){
                   alert(result);

                }

           });
    });
 });
```

try this way...

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry for late response.
I was out of connection.
Your solution worked partially !
Now what's happening, Ajax request also going with form validation.
On submit where validation called, on the same time ajax request also goes and responds. I want to send this ajax call later when the form is completely filled with validations.

Comment: What does it return ?

Comment: it returns empty alert message as soon as i clicked on submit first

Comment: It should first confirm whether the form is validated or not and then ajax call should work !

Comment: If you want to call ajax after validation check then read the validation check plugin documentation . I am sure you will be able to find some callback or some function you can run after validation fails or succeed. Also try adding echo "test"; in your server side to see if ajax actually returns something from your server side function/script

Comment: Firstly on clicking submit, ajax request returns an empty alert message. When i filled the form, then on clicking submit, it return true echo value that i want in respond.

Comment: Actually i have no idea that before taken any action, how to check whether the form is validated or not. That's why, i posted this problem here :(

Comment: For you time, i would like to appreciate your effort so you deserve up-vote.